# Magento - WYSIWYG for promotions descriptions field

Tags: magento

When you set up a sales promotion you have the option to put in some text describing what the offer actually is. I am using this text on the front end by pulling through the collections of the sales and catalog rules, then iterating over them to check they are active, in date and applicable to the customer group. Right now I have this code in a phtml file that I can include with layout update on a special offers page. It summarises the offers including cart 'bogof' and free shipping setups. When an offer expires it automatically drops from the list. The idea is that there is less maintenance needed to put offers up.

So far so good, however, I would like to be able to edit this description field with the wysiwyg.

EDIT:

Here is what I came up with, thanks to the tips kindly given below...

In app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/promo.xml

After

```
<adminhtml_promo_catalog_edit>
```

I added:

```
    <update handle="editor"/>
```

After

```
<adminhtml_promo_quote_edit>
```

I added the same 'editor' update layout handle xml tag.

Note that this change is not part of an admin design override and will be lost next time an upgrade comes out.

I then copied

app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Promo/Catalog/Edit/Form.php to local and added:

```
 protected function _prepareLayout()
 {
     Mage::log("Prepare Layout");
     parent::_prepareLayout();
     if (Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->isEnabled()) {
         $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadTinyMce(true);
     }
 }
```

I also copied app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Promo/Catalog/Edit/Tab/Main.php across to local.

At the top of _prepareForm() I added:

```
$wysiwygConfig = Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->getConfig(array('add_variables' => false, 'add_widgets' => false,'files_browser_window_url'=>Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->getUrl('*/cms_wysiwyg_images/index')));
```

And then updated the description field:

```
    $fieldset->addField('description', 'editor', array(
        'name' => 'description',
        'label' => Mage::helper('catalogrule')->__('Details'),
        'title' => Mage::helper('catalogrule')->__('Details'),
        'style' => 'width: 50em; height: 20em;',
        'config'    => $wysiwygConfig,
    ));
```

I then did the same for the 'quote' forms, so my new forms in local are:

app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Promo/Catalog/Edit/Form.php
app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Promo/Catalog/Edit/Tab/Main.php
app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Promo/Quote/Edit/Form.php
app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Promo/Quote/Edit/Tab/Main.php

This now works a treat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is the link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/173868/#t304763) :) enjoy i have tested it on all 1.4, 1.5 and 1.6.

But do read the post till end before applying, the only problem that you will encounter has the solution at the end.

Comment: Took me a while and some perseverance, but thanks a lot for the tip.